# Mocking External JS Library in Angular Unit Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

### How do I mock a third party library in my Unit Test

I am writing Jest-based Unit Tests for my Angular application. I'm stuck figuring out how to mock the LeaderLine Library.

In my component I have a function responsible for constructing LeaderLines between elements on the page. In my Jest test, when I call the function to construct the lines I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

##### LeadLine Constructor

```js
this.routingToValidation = new LeaderLine(
        this.transformDiv.nativeElement,
        this.validateXmlPanel.nativeElement,
        {
          endPlug: 'arrow3',
          color: 'darkgray',
          startSocket: 'right',
          endSocket: 'top',
          path: 'grid',
          middleLabel: LeaderLine.captionLabel('Transformed Data Routing To', {
            color: 'black',
            fontSize: '14px',
          }),
        }
      );
```

##### Unit Test So Far

```js
it('[constructRoutingLines] - should create routing lines between components (validate xml = true)', () => {
      componentSpy = jest.spyOn(component, 'removeConnectionsFromDOM').mockImplementation();
      const spinnerSpy = jest.spyOn(spinnerService, 'hide');

      component.constructRoutingLines();

      expect(componentSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(spinnerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

I'm using a port of the original LeaderLine JS library that supports typescript ([leader-line-new](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leader-line-new)).

I don't necessarily need to test LeaderLines are constructed or exist in the DOM, but need to ensure the variable references are set, but I can't get past this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used that lib but I see it is not imported, it is added with the script tag. I usually mock it in the `setupTests.js` config file for the `jest`.

```js
global.SomeExternalLib = {
  someMethod: () => "this is the mocked implementation"
}
```